# How can I reduce startup time for vim?

Tags: vim

This is [My vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/158cf2070e2b9b76505912a50588e390723bb70f/Configurations/vimrc)

I found load .vimrc would take long time in terminal:

```
$ vim --startuptime myvimrctime
$ cat myvimrctime
....
152.762  147.219  054.849: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
....
```

I've done some optimization for [viminfo](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/158cf2070e2b9b76505912a50588e390723bb70f/Configurations/vimrc#L52):

```
  set viminfo=%,<800,'10,/50,:100,h,f0,n~/.vim/cache/.viminfo
```

But it still take too much time.

This is `time vim`:

```
[marslo@MarsloJiao ~]
$ time vim
real    0m1.877s
user    0m0.204s
sys         0m0.028s
```

How can I reduce the startup time for my vim? Thanks.

---

By the way, here three items are also take much times as below, is there any way I can start these files after vim started:

```
050.213  043.340  043.340: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
050.334  044.509  000.409: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
143.985  040.931  037.467: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
```

And the strange is, the clock from **054.490** jump to **141.158** by no reason (vundle config only take 000.184):

```
054.490  000.184  000.184: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
141.158  002.377  002.377: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
```

---

I've create new --startuptime file again. The following is the fully log:

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.013  000.013: --- VIM STARTING ---
050.538  050.525: Allocated generic buffers
110.662  060.124: locale set
124.156  013.494: GUI prepared
222.567  098.411: clipboard setup
222.610  000.043: window checked
465.327  242.717: inits 1
465.344  000.017: parsing arguments
465.348  000.004: expanding arguments
465.383  000.035: shell init
465.846  000.463: Termcap init
465.912  000.066: inits 2
466.107  000.195: init highlight
682.019  000.574  000.574: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
682.360  001.624  001.050: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
740.232  031.815  031.815: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
740.351  073.003  039.564: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
740.490  000.023  000.023: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
784.275  000.101  000.101: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
863.519  056.517  056.517: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/macros/matchit.vim
865.282  001.188  001.188: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
1000.218  000.258  000.258: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle.vim
1054.471  000.234  000.234: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
1585.009  002.401  002.401: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
1589.847  000.516  000.516: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/ftdetect/javascript.vim
1600.298  000.232  000.232: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript-syntax/ftdetect/javascript.vim
1609.818  000.376  000.376: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/ftdetect/mkd.vim
1638.215  124.558  121.033: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
1640.109  000.055  000.055: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
1651.369  000.189  000.189: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
1681.203  000.767  000.767: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
1686.380  000.729  000.729: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
1689.126  000.719  000.719: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
1691.276  027.443  025.228: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/marslo.vim/colors/marslo256.vim
1692.803  1160.345  877.776: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
1692.839  066.387: sourcing vimrc file(s)
1720.420  000.418  000.418: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
1720.883  009.810  009.392: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim
1742.318  001.396  001.396: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim
1747.987  000.292  000.292: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/authorinfo/plugin/authorinfo.vim
1758.222  003.409  003.409: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/EnhCommentify.vim/plugin/EnhancedCommentify.vim
1779.670  002.103  002.103: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/supertab/plugin/supertab.vim
1788.557  001.838  001.838: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/auto-pairs/plugin/auto-pairs.vim
1809.937  001.491  001.491: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/plugin/snipMate.vim
1813.891  000.471  000.471: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/Conque-Shell/plugin/conque_term.vim
1854.376  019.755  019.755: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/mru.vim/plugin/mru.vim
1856.948  001.377  001.377: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/taglist.vim/plugin/taglist.vim
1877.552  003.597  003.597: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/winmanager/plugin/winfileexplorer.vim
1882.273  004.192  004.192: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/winmanager/plugin/winmanager.vim
1894.960  001.489  001.489: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/winmanager/plugin/wintagexplorer.vim
1918.938  000.482  000.482: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/python_fold/plugin/python_fold.vim
1944.447  001.214  001.214: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/plugin/rails.vim
1998.414  002.073  002.073: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-textobj-user/autoload/textobj/user.vim
2015.845  048.452  046.379: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-textobj-rubyblock/plugin/textobj/rubyblock.vim
2034.279  000.329  000.329: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/ruby-matchit/plugin/ruby-matchit.vim
2063.907  001.131  001.131: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim
2105.056  018.511  018.511: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/rainbow/plugin/rainbow.vim
2130.447  000.401  000.401: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
2131.959  000.904  000.904: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
2132.955  000.557  000.557: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
2134.955  001.501  001.501: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
2135.455  000.100  000.100: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
2135.852  000.084  000.084: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
2136.666  000.501  000.501: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
2137.312  000.215  000.215: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
2137.972  000.335  000.335: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
2138.870  000.540  000.540: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/tools/vim74/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
2157.065  000.696  000.696: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/indentLine/after/plugin/indentLine.vim
2184.847  006.999  006.999: sourcing /home/marslo/.vim/bundle/snipmate.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
2185.397  359.386: loading plugins
2187.454  002.057: inits 3
2195.983  008.529: reading viminfo
2242.679  046.696: setup clipboard
2242.716  000.037: setting raw mode
2242.760  000.044: start termcap
2242.859  000.099: clearing screen
2247.092  004.233: opening buffers
2248.580  001.488: BufEnter autocommands
2248.593  000.013: editing files in windows
2249.224  000.631: VimEnter autocommands
2249.231  000.007: before starting main loop
2251.990  002.759: first screen update
2251.999  000.009: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Comment: how do you know your vim starting took 1.47s? the startuptime file has `ms`. and the result of your command `time vim` doesn't make sense, it depends on how fast you quit vim. if you opened vim and wait 5mins, then exit, the real would be 5mins.

Comment: Okay, I don't wait 5 mins now, But my vim start really slow.

Comment: @Kent Should I calculate from clock (the first column)?

Comment: Try to remove vundle from the mix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `~/.vimrc` is sourced, it means that every line is evaluated by Vim upon initialization, including all your functions. You should move all your functions to the autoload directory. See `:help autoload` for the details but here is a simplified example.

If you had this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
function! MyFunc()
    " code
endfunction

autocmd BufWinEnter * call MyFunc()
```

You could create `~/.vim/autoload/functions.vim` and move the function in there:

```
function functions#MyFunc()
    " code
endfunction
```

and leave just this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * call functions#MyFunc()
```

In that form Vim will not need to parse the function until it is actually called.

---

Another optimization could be to move all your `autocmd FileType` to proper ftplugins.

Now, in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType ruby setlocal something
```

After, in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`:

```
setlocal something
```

Comment: Did you mean I should make my functions to a plugin?

Comment: No. The idea is to move them out of the way so that vim doesn't evaluete them when it sources your vimrc. That's the whole point of `autoload`.

Comment: And, what `autocmd BufWinEnter * call MyFunc()` measn? Mapping another command? I always call MyFunc() by run `:call MyFunc()`.

Comment: That example is taken from your vimrc. You should create commands or mappings instead of doing :call, that's more typing than its worth.

Comment: Yep, my function is too ... stupid...  I'd the way you showed to me.

Comment: I still have an question. Why leave `autocmd BufWinEnter * call functions#MyFunc()` in .vimrc? The plugin which I used are all needn't call the function in vimrc.

Comment: I don't know why exactly you did things the way you did. There are lots and lots of optimizations you can do all over the place. Once you have moved all your functions to the autoload directory you have to change all their calls from `call MyFunc()` to `call functions#MyFunc()` that's for sure. Whether that's in your vimrc or elsewhere is your call.

Comment: Alright, I've done the autoload sutff as you said already. [This is My function](https://github.com/Marslo/MarsloFunc/blob/master/autoload/marslofunc.vim), and [This is my vimrc](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc#L102). I will test the startup time after reboot.

Comment: That's pretty. The original time is 2215+ ms, now is 1446 ms

Comment: And, I've remove the function about **remember the last location**, I think that might help the optimization too.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should switch from Vundle to NeoBundle. It has `NeoBundleLazy` option that automatically loads plugin only when it is requested. Its upon you to decide how is this achieved. It supports activation by command, mapping, filetype, calls by other plugins like `unite`, etc.

For instance, take a look at parts from my vimrc:

```
NeoBundleLazy 'klen/python-mode'          , { 'filetypes' : ['python'] }
NeoBundleLazy 'Decho'                     , { 'filetypes' : ['vim']  }
NeoBundleLazy 'othree/html5.vim'          , { 'filetypes' : [ 'html', 'css' ] } }
NeoBundleLazy 'majkinetor/unite-cmdmatch' , { 'depends': 'Shougo/unite.vim' , 'mappings' : [['c' , '<Plug>(unite_cmdmatch_complete)']] }
```

Above code means that first 3 plugins will be loaded only when specific file types are opened but last one will load as soon as you press mapping defined by plugin (which itself is mapped by `cmap`).

There is also a way to group your plugin sets into functions and load them all at once (via hotkey for example or manually).

Comment: "What filetype is open" means? If I set `fileytype plugin indent on` in vimrc, means all filetype are all opened?

Comment: That means that plugin will load once you open specific filetype(s). This is something you can easily accomplish by `au` BUT that is not good approach: command is decoupled from plugin loading while it shouldn't be. Besides, NeoBundleLazy supports bunch of additional options that are harder to accomplish in single command and if you wanted to use them all it would make your vimrc ugly.